# Entity framework Validation errors has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting this Entity Framework error when I try to save an object in my Database context.
I have no idea where to start looking.

What could be happening here?

How can I isolate what the issue is?

Thanks.

```
{System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Exception' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'AssemblyName' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'CultureInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'DateTimeFormatInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'IdentityReference' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Exceptions' is based on type 'Exception' that has no keys defined.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'AssemblyNames' is based on type 'AssemblyName' that has no keys defined.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'CultureInfoes' is based on type 'CultureInfo' that has no keys defined.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'DateTimeFormatInfoes' is based on type 'DateTimeFormatInfo' that has no keys defined.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityReferences' is based on type 'IdentityReference' that has no keys defined.

   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ValidateAndSerializeCsdl(EdmModel model, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ValidateCsdl(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at MVCDaemon.Controllers.AwardBadgesController.FromUnprocessedEvents() in Hobby Stuff\Hehe\Hehe.Daemon\Controllers\AwardBadgesController.cs:line 58}
```

and my other stuff:

```
DaemonDB.Tasks.Add(T);
```

and

```
public class DaemonDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DaemonDBContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        //Collections also in BaseDBContext:
        public DbSet<Badge> Badges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BadgeGroup> BadgeGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

        //Collections only in DaemonDBContext
        public DbSet<EventCheckedForBadgeReward> EventCheckedForBadgeReward { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Task
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FriendlyTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOfExecution { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan LengthOfExecution { get; set; }
        public Stopwatch StopWatch;
        public Exception ExceptionEncountered { get; set; }

        public Task() {
            TimeOfExecution = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void StartStopwatch()
        {
            StopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            StopWatch.Start();
        }

        public void StopStopwatch()
        {
            StopWatch.Stop();
        }

        public string GetStatusAsFriendly()
        {
            return ExceptionEncountered == null ? "Success" : "Failed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you save an Exception in a database, or a StopWatch?  EF thinks these are tables you've created in the database and is looking to reference them and grab some foreign keys to put in your Tasks table.  EF just likes dealing with data, it is confused.  You can start by making those members private, or better yet separating out the data you want to persist from the class that creates it.

Comment: What does your task database table look like? Could you post the table definition?

Comment: Thanks dbugger, that was it!!!!

Comment: First create primary key then it will resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use [NotMapped] attribute on some properties.